# Change Bootstrap label position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to get Bootstrap label and textbox to the same line (in here I need to get label to be in front of the textbox)

Code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total Tax</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tottax" />
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h26d70k9/)**

Comment: Are you just trying to do [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use row's within rows to solve something like this.

This code works for me:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 pull-left">
            <label class="control-label">Total Tax</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tottax" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d2kt0kp2/

Comment: Please do not use **row** inside **form-group**. Both **row** and **form-group** have `margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;`. So you'll end up with **-30px;** Besides, you do not need `<div class="col-md-6 pull-left">`; instead, you want to combine those styles to **label**.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use **form-horizontal** if you want to display like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h26d70k9/2/).

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 control-label">VAT</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">            
            <textbox class="form-control">teetetet</textbox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h26d70k9/2/

Comment: This answer is actually better than mine. I was trying to do this quick on my iPad.